# Powershell: Cannot access registry value

Tags: powershell

I need to get value for "UninstallString" in

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
{1535CAA3-9F33-414E-8987-0365169BE741}

calling:

```
Get-Item -path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{1535CAA3-9F33-414E-8987-0365169BE741}
```

results in
*Get-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '1535CAA3-9F33-414E-8987-0365169BE741'.*

Comment: you need to wrap the path in `""`.  But even if you do that I don't think you can access the registry value like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement [js2010's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74394563/45375), which notes that *lack of quoting* is your primary problem (`{` and `}` are PowerShell *metacharacters*):

In PowerShell v5 and above, you can use the [`Get-ItemPropertyValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itempropertyvalue) cmdlet to directly return the data associated with a registry key's *value*:

```
# Note the use of '...' around the registry path 
# and the value name UninstallString at the end.
Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{1535CAA3-9F33-414E-8987-0365169BE741}' UninstallString
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

An *unquoted* argument such as `HKLM:\...\{1535CAA3-9F33-414E-8987-0365169BE741}` is processed as follows:

- Because `{...}` creates a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks), it is considered the start of a *separate* argument, and *string* `'HKLM:\...\'` and *script block* `{1535CAA3-9F33-414E-8987-0365169BE741}` are passed as *two* arguments.
- Because [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item) didn't expect an *extra* (positional) argument, it complained accordingly, and used the *string representation* of the script block in its error message.

  - A script block's string representation is its *verbatim content*, excluding `{` and `}`, which you can verify with `{1535CAA3-9F33-414E-8987-0365169BE741}.ToString()`

As noted, *quoting* is the solution, and since the path contains neither PowerShell variable references nor subexpressions, using a [*single-quoted*, i.e. *verbatim* string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) (`'...'`) is best.

The (usually less desirable) alternative is to stick with an *unquoted* argument and use *individual escaping* of PowerShell metacharacters with `` ` `` (the so-called backtick); e.g.:
`` Write-Output HKLM:\...\`{1535CAA3-9F33-414E-8987-0365169BE741`} ``

Comment: that explains why I it worked just fine for values without curly braces '{'. another lesson learned!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @yBother.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this with quotes, since curly brackets look like a scriptblock to powershell:

```
get-itemproperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{013DB423-A8DE-4423-9E50-D45ED1041789}' uninstallstring | 
  % uninstallstring

MsiExec.exe /I{013DB423-A8DE-4423-9E50-D45ED1041789}
```

Although for an msi you can uninstall with this in powershell 5.1:

```
get-package *chrome* | uninstall-package
```

For other non-msi installs the uninstallstring is here.  Usually you have to add an extra option like "/S" for silent uninstall.

```
get-package *firefox* | % { $_.metadata['uninstallstring'] }

"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\uninstall\helper.exe"
```

Answer (score -1):

As I commented you need to wrap the path in `""` however that still won't work.  To get a registry value in powershell use `Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\...` as the path.  And once you get the `RegistryKey` object you can use `GetValue(string name)` to get the value of `UninstallString`.  So your command would look something like this:

```
(Get-Item -path "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{1535CAA3-9F33-414E-8987-0365169BE741}").GetValue("UninstallString")
```

Comment: Good point about needing quoting, but a `HKLM:` path work just fine in PowerShell: there are two registry "drives" predefined in PowerShell `HKLM:` (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`) and `HKCU:` (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER`) - run `Get-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry` to verify.

Comment: Also note that in PSv5+ you can use `Get-ItemPropertyValue`: `Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{1535CAA3-9F33-414E-8987-0365169BE741}' UninstallString`